# Entries must be arrays of the form [key: string, value: string], JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: firebase, react-native, asyncstorage

> In Android, it is working fine but I'm getting an issue on iOS. When
> I'm dismissing the error by clicking on Dismiss, it is working for me.

**Error**

```
Error: {
    message = "Entries must be arrays of the form [key: string, value: string], got: (\n    notificationCount\n)";
}
```

**Environment**

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.6",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.4.3",
```

Comment: This happens on ios if either key or value is null/undefined in async-storage.
reference [github](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/190)

Answer (score 1):

Pass value in AsyncStorage as JSON.stringify its solve your problem for example

```js
testFunction =async()=>{
  let arr = await AsyncStorage.multiset([JSON.stringify(token)])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md) can access AsyncStorage synchronously, and can also store and retrieve objects, strings or Boolean data，maybe can help you.